# Word conversion

Tags: python

How do i convert the original verse to the converted verse?

It should convert `cubits` to `feet`

Original Verse:

> "So make yourself an ark of cypress wood; make rooms in it and coat it
>   with pitch inside and out.  This is how you are to build it: The ark
>   is to be 300 cubits long, 50 cubits wide and 30 cubits high.  (Genesis
>   6:14-15)"

Converted Verse:

> "So make yourself an ark of cypress wood; make rooms in it and coat it
>   with pitch inside and out.  This is how you are to build it: The ark
>   is to be 450 feet long, 75 feet wide and 45 feet high.  (Genesis
>   6:14-15)"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're expected to try to [solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Hint: Regex match on `(\d+) (cubits)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could match a regular expression, and use a replacement function to adjust units (and change unit name)

```
import re

r = re.compile("(\d+) cubits")

s = "So make yourself an ark of cypress wood; make rooms in it and coat it with pitch inside and out. This is how you are to build it: The ark is to be 300 cubits long, 50 cubits wide and 30 cubits high. (Genesis 6:14-15)"

print(r.sub(lambda m : "{} feet".format(int(float(m.group(1))*1.5)),s))
```

result:

> So make yourself an ark of cypress wood; make rooms in it and coat it with pitch inside and out. This is how you are to build it: The ark is to be 450 feet long, 75 feet wide and 45 feet high. (Genesis 6:14-15)

When the regular expression matches a number followed by "cubits", it calls the lambda callback, parses the number, multiplies by 1.5, converts back to integer and reformat the output with the new unit.

This would have to be finetuned for 1 foot, and could use a conversion dictionary if there were to be more units to convert.

Answer (score 1):

Take each word, then check for the values

Something like so

```
conversion_factor = 1.5
words = verse.split()
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if i < len(words)-1 and words[i+1] == 'cubits':
        amount = int(word)
        word = int(amount * conversion_factor)
    if word == 'cubits':
        word = 'feet'
    print(word, end = ' ')
```

output

`"So make yourself an ark of cypress wood; make rooms in it and coat it with pitch inside and out. This is how you are to build it: The ark is to be 450 feet long, 75 feet wide and 45 feet high. (Genesis 6:14-15)"`